# driver.switchTo.frame is not a function

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am new to Selenium. Here is the task:

1. Open https://pastebin.com
2. Paste "Hello from WebDriver"
3. Set past expiration to 10 Minutes //I am having problems here
4. Set paste title as "helloweb"

I am using javascript, with chromedriver

I am able to open the dropdown but cant choose the expiration time, it says:

```
ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted: Element <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">...</span> is not clickable at point (422, 569). Other element would receive the click: <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://9c4fe1b6ba8be5733ce3e7442f84515f.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-38/html/container.html"
id="google_adsiframe/22653346938/12825_Pastebin.com/12825_Pastebin.com_SmartBanner_1_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="970" height="90" data-is-safeframe="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" role="region" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" data-google-container-id="1" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
```

So i found out that the choices are hidden inside a frame(i am new to this). I used driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(xpath)) function

Here is my code:

```
const { Browser } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { waitForServer } = require('selenium-webdriver/http/util');
(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  try {
    await driver.get('https://pastebin.com');

    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="postform-text"]')).sendKeys('Hello from WebDriver');
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="w0"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span/span[1]/span/span[2]')).click()
    await driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="postform-expiration"]/option[3]'))).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="postform-name"]')).sendKeys('helloweb');
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="w0"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[8]/button')).click();
  }
  finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

But it says "driver.switchTo.frame is not a function". How can i fix this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Remove .click() from switch to frame line code.

```
await driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="postform-expiration"]/option[3]')));
```

Comment: thank you! but now im having another `error ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted: Element <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="3" style="width: 100%;">...</span> is not clickable at point (301, 49). Other element would receive the click: <div class="header__links h_1024">...</div>`